# Как помочь псевдоэлементу вылазить за пределы родительского блока?

Tags: html, css

[image: Как помочь псевдоэлементу вылазить за пределы родительского блока?]

Надо помочь псевдоэлементу вылезти за пределы родительского блока 70рх на 20рх.
После его добавления он попросту обрезается. Не помогает выравнивание `top/left -> position:absolute`
Стили псевдоэлемента:

```css
&:before {
          content: '';
          .size(68px,25px);
          position: absolute;
          background: url("../images/active-cell.svg");
        }
```

Стили родительского:

```css
.default {
        width: 70px;
        cursor: move;
        display: table-cell;
        border-left: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        line-height: 19px;
        padding-left: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: black;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
```

Есть еще один вариант как можно это сделать, но не хочу задействовать js

Comment: ` overflow: hidden;` у родителя убери

Comment: @pepel_xD пробовал, да и решение уже нашел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В родительский элемент добавил свойство `overflow: visible;`